# Using Multiple Cultures in .NET CORE 3.1 Web App

Tags: .net-core, culture

We have a web app that displays data from a couple of different web apps. In each of those web apps, the culture is configurable (it is set by a company admin at the app level for all users, not per user).

In our web app, we need to display the data from each of the other web apps, in the culture configured for that app. The only good news is that currently we don't display "mixed" data from both apps, in a single view. And generally, a controller and all of its actions will only work with data from a single app (meaning that all actions from that controller will use the same culture).

**There are several things I'm struggling with:**

1. Does .NET Core really not honor setting culture like in the old days? I've tried it but it doesn't work (unless I'm setting it in the wrong place in the pipeline).

   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = firstWebAppCultureInfo;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = firstWebAppCultureInfo;

Does it really only check these to find and set the culture?

```
QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
CookieRequestCultureProvider
AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider
```

I know I could write a custom provider, but that wouldn't seem to help me. We already get the various culture settings for the apps, from a database and store them in session.

2. My first thought was to write out a Culture Cookie every time the user hits a controller. I'd read the culture from session and write the cookie. But there are a couple of issues I see with this.

**Issue 1:** If I write the cookie out in the controller action, it doesn't "take affect" the first time it is changed from one culture to another. Obviously the cookie has already been read and the culture has already been set for that request. I'm too late in the pipeline to do that.

I tried writing the cookie out in the constructor of the controller (or constructor of a base controller) but HttpContext is not yet set at that point (it is null).

I have worked a bit with Filters and I will write an Action Filter that writes the cookie to see if that works, but see Issue 2.

**Issue 2:** Another issue would surface if the user opened multiple instances of their browser. The last culture written will "win" I suspect. So if a user is displaying data in Culture fr-FR in one browser and en-US in another instance of a browser and navigates to a controller/view that writes that en-US cookie, and then from the other browser instance navigates to a page that is supposed to use the fr-FR culture, the user would get the en-US setting from the cookie and that's not acceptable.

3. I don't really want to use the QueryStringRequestCultureProvider, because having that show up in the url is ugly.

I'm definitely not an expert in this area.

What am I missing?
How would you all implement this?

Thanks in Advance.

**UPDATE**

I created an ActionFilter and TypeFilterAttribute that allows me to pass a parameter into the ActionFilter. Using the parameter I can decide which key to read from Session to give me the culture setting I've stored for each web app.

From there I can mark each controller with that attribute and the appropriate parameter to tell the action filter what culture to use (remember we don't mix data, so each controller displays views that show data from only one of the two web apps, not both).

In the ActionFilter I can look up the culture string from session and do the following and it works:

```
    var ci = new CultureInfo(this.cultureSetting);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

While that is encouraging, it feels hacky. So please comment on the solution...

I'd like to find a way to do all of this in a BaseController or somewhere, so I wouldn't need to put attributes on all of our controllers.

But whatever I've tried in a base controller seems like it is either:
a) too late in the pipeline to set the culture for that request, or
b) too early in the pipeline to get access to httpcontext.

Thoughts? Ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

I guess overriding OnActionExecuting in my base controller lets me do the same things as the ActionFilter...

So I guess I have a solution, but if anyone has a better idea, I'm listening.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to go with an ActionFilter for our solution, so we can mark Controllers and/or Actions with an Attribute that indicates which app we are getting data from, so we can apply that app's culture setting...